# Send data to WEB SERVER from ANDROID

Tags: php, android, post

My app has to scan a QR Code and send result (string) to a Web Server since i wanna visualize it on my web page. Inside my php page i put this

```
 <?php
     // get the "message" variable from the post request
     // this is the data coming from the Android app
     $message=$_POST["message"]; 
     // specify the file where we will save the contents of the variable message
     $filename="androidmessages.html";
     // write the data to the file

     file_put_contents($filename,$message,FILE_APPEND);
     // load the contents of the file to a variable
     $androidmessages=file_get_contents($filename);
     // display the contents of the variable (which has the contents of the file)
     echo $androidmessages; ?>
```

All works properly, but  FILE_APPEND  appends every result and i want to visualize only the current scanning !
So, i tried to use

```
file_put_contents($filename,$message);
```

but what i visualize is a blank page !!! WHY ???

Comment: Start wich checking the return value of file_put_contents(). Then have a look at other FILE_.... flags.

Comment: Probably because you did not send anything in the `$_POST['message']` field.

Comment: no, i send something since  with  FILE_APPEND  i can visualize on my webpage the scan result !